# After ibus-pinyin installation, I can't insert accented characters in LibreOffice

Tags: debian, keyboard, libreoffice, special-characters, characters

I'm using *Debian 3.16.39-1* (amd64) and *LibreOffice 4.3.3.2*. I've recently installed *ibus-pinyin*. I'm using *ibus* Spanish keyboard layout to write, which includes accent keys that combine automatically in any text field to produce accented letters [i.e. à, é, ü, etc]. Nevertheless, and this is the weird thing, as soon as I focus in a different window than the one displaying the document in LibreOffice, I stop being able to write accented characters in the writer. Moreover, if I a get back to the doc and apply a paragraph style, I can anew write accented characters.

As you might see, the situation is kind of confusing and definitely a pain in the ass. I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Do you?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally solved my problem. The issue was related to the fact that I installed *ibus-pinyin* yet I didn't reconfigure my locales with `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Once I did it, everything started to work correctly.